# how to debug/fix azure import api swagger errors?

Tags: azure

I'm trying to import an API via its Swagger spec through Azure API Management. The swagger url that I'm using displays the swagger page as expected. However, when I try to import the swagger I get the following error:

"Parsing error(s): Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0."

It doesn't make sense to me that I'd be able to open a swagger doc without error but attempting to import the Swagger API would encounter this error through the "Import API" view of APIM.  Any ideas about the root cause or how to debug/fix?

Comment: Is your app an App Service API App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That typically means your service is providing XML instead of JSON.  I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you've put in the URL to your swagger-ui, rather than the swagger definition.

If you're using the generic swagger-ui, look in the URL field in the green box.  Put that in the import box, not the address of the swagger-ui HTML page.